# How can I upload folders to Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

How can I upload complete folders to my Google Cloud Storage? I tried using Cyberduck, but I can't get my Google login info to work with it. Any ideas for a medium-skill level Mac user to easily upload complete folders rather than files?

Comment: When you tried Cyberduck, did you have a look at this guide? http://trac.cyberduck.ch/wiki/help/en/howto/googlestorage

Answer (score 23):

You can use [`gsutil cp`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) in the Terminal for bulk uploads/downloads:

```
gsutil -m cp -R dir gs://my_bucket
```

The `-m` flag will perform a parallel (multi-threaded) copy.

Comment: I am surprised not more people has searched for this.

Comment: this will upload only the files from the folder dir, not sub-folders. Not really recursively, regardless to -R flag

Comment: @ses – [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/cp) I linked to say: _"The -R and -r options are synonymous. Causes directories, buckets, and bucket subdirectories to be copied recursively. If you neglect to use this option for an upload, gsutil will copy any files it finds and skip any directories. Similarly, neglecting to specify this option for a download will cause gsutil to copy any objects at the current bucket directory level, and skip any subdirectories."_ — if you are not seeing the correct behavior, please file a bug or post a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily upload folders from your local computer using the Google Cloud Console with no special tools.

Just click the left hand navigation 
Storage > Cloud Storage > Browser 
using in the Google Cloud Console: https://console.developers.google.com

Create a bucket or select an existing one

Then click "Upload folder"

You'll get a sidebar that will pop out notifying you of the upload progress.

Answer (score 1):

Just for completeness, I show how to:

1. Get started (login, set project)
2. Upload the files
3. List the items
4. Download the files
   An alternative to cp is to use [rsync](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/rsync) which is not demonstrated here.

Start the session, set the project and see the current configuration:

```
gcloud auth login
gcloud config set project PROJECT_ID
gcloud config list
```

Create test tree folder structure to upload

```
echo 'test content: foo BAR" > ec2-iamrole.yaml
mkdir -p level1/level2
cp ec2-iamrole.yaml level1
cp ec2-iamrole.yaml level1/level2
rm ec2-iamrole.yaml level1
```

To upload (bucket was already created and it has a folder name sample)

```
gsutil -m cp -R level1 gs://my_bucket/sample
```

To create the bucket, check [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/creating-buckets). In addition, you cannot create single folders using **gsutil** command. You need to use the GCP UI or user the client library or explicitly specifying it in the command as I just did above.

List content:

```
gsutil ls -r gs://my_bucket/sample/level1
```

Output:

```
gs://my_bucket/sample/level1/:
gs://my_bucket/sample/level1/ec2-iamrole.yaml

gs://my_bucket/sample/level1/level2/:
gs://my_bucket/sample/level1/level2/ec2-iamrole.yaml
```

Download into a new folder `level3`:

```
mkdir level3 && cd level3
gsutil -m cp -R gs://docexporter/nov/level1 .
```

Output:

```
tree .
.
└── level1
    ├── ec2-iamrole.yaml
    └── level2
        └── ec2-iamrole.yaml

2 directories, 2 files
```

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the Google Drive web app and click the upload icon, then folder. Or better you can download the [Google Drive Desktop application](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/drive) and then simply copy-and-paste your required folder in the Google Drive folder. With this, the folder and all its files will get synced up with the cloud.

Comment: Thanks Anuj - but is "Google Drive" the same as "Google Cloud"? I thought Drive was a separate kind of account?

Comment: Google Drive uses the cloud storage. Like Dropbox or any other services for cloud storage. @user2370921

Comment: While Google Drive *uses* Google Cloud Storage, they are not identical. Drive is basically an application that runs on Cloud Storage. But you can't access your Cloud Storage buckets through Drive.